# Why is simple JQuery dialog/popup not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I put it all in one page and it should work and is not working:

```
<html>
<head>  <link href="css_js/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="JavaScript1.2" src="css_js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript1.2" src="css_js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">
function popup() {
    alert('test');
    var popup = $('.newpopup');
    popup.draggable();
    popup.resizable();
    popup.html('<p>Where is pancakes house?</p>');
    popup.show('fast');
}
$('button').click(popup);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='newpopup'></div>
<button>popup</button>  
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make a simple popup / dialog with Jquery but it is not working at all. What is wrong with it?

Comment: remove the `language` attribute.

Comment: is `$('button')` a valid trigger to use?

Comment: it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/djgHr/

Comment: you are loading the button element after attempting to bind the event to it, i.e. there is nothing to bind the event to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the function on `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     popup();
  });
})
```

OR

```
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     popup();
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now I only need to position the popup and recode it so that it works with several popups on the same page. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @NickRosencrantz Create a plugin of that function and apply it to multiple elements - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 0):

You should run your function in jQuery style:

```
$('button').click(function() { 
     popup();
     return false; //optional
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `src` reference is valid when you're including jquery? I've got your code [working fine on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24nLZ/) using the Google-hosted versions of JQuery and JQuery-ui.

Comment: jsfiddle puts the js inside a window load event, that's why it's working there but not for him.

Comment: Ah, OK - I didn't realise. Thanks.